# SSIS Derived Column showing anerror saying out of memory

Tags: ssis, derived

The Below Derived Column is showing error in SSIS

CASE TRIM(UPPER(IssueReviewYN))    WHEN "YES" THEN 0    WHEN "N/A" THEN 0    ELSE 1 END

Is there anything i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the expression is showing an error is you have valid TSQL but a Derived Column uses the SSIS [Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/integration-services-ssis-expressions) language which is not SQL.

You're looking for the [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/conditional-ssis-expression)

```
(test) ? trueCase : falseCase
```

You are looking for something along the lines of

```
(TRIM(UPPER(IssueReviewYN)) == "YES" || TRIM(UPPER(IssueReviewYN)) == "N/A") ? 0 : 1
```

Pseudo logic: if the uppercased and trimmed value of `IssueReviewYN` is YES or N/A then use 0; else 1